# Using Postman with a POST to backend service, getting 431 Request Header Fields Too Large

Tags: node.js, docker, kubernetes, post, postman

I am developing and testing a Node.js back-end service that uses an endpoint to receive requests and data. I tested this service in Visual Code running locally (http://localhost:8098) using Postman. The POST to the URL works fine locally.

But when I deploy the service to Azure or to an Ubuntu server VM (as a Docker image in a Kubernetes pod) and test it with Postman, I receive the aforementioned 431 error.

I have the minimum header fields that Postman adds to the request, so it is definitely not a header fields too large issue. The problem must lie elsewhere, but I have no idea where to look.

I have developed and deployed multiple back-end services to the same web app prior to this one with no issues. I used one of those services as a template to build this one.

I'm not sure what to add as information, but I will add any information requested. I am at wits end with this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Code:

```
let router = require('express').Router()

// Test
router.post('/test/', auth.optional, async function (req, res) {
  console.log('Inbound request:')
  console.log(req.headers)
//  let context = req.context
//  req.body.tenant_id = req.auth.tenantId
  const result = await commsysEventService.test(req.body)
  res.json(result)
})

module.exports = router
```

The code is as simple as can be. The code never even makes it to the console.log lines.

From Postman:

[Postman screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzILv.png)

Comment: Yes, please post code.

Comment: If the code that you posted is not reached, the problem must be with other code that is executed earlier, and which you have not posted.